# How to read java map recursively

Tags: java, dictionary, recursion

I have Java map like below. I would like to read all the values where keys can be value of other keys. Here I am trying to write some repercussion method to read it but no luck. If someone experienced please explain me.

```
Map map= new HashMap();
map.put("a", "1");
map.put("b", "2");
map.put("c", "3");
map.put("1", "4");
map.put("4", "5");
```

in the above map if I pass `"a"` as key I want all the values corresponding to a that is `1,4,5`

Comment: You could do this with a loop. What have you tried? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: What if there is an infinite loop? e.g. `1` goes to `2`, `2` goes to `1`.

Comment: Then you may have a control check to see if you already read that key before.

Comment: fortunately these is no infinite loop .. but only thing keys as values as many time in the map

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't have any loop:

```
private String mapRecursion(Map<String,String> map, String key) {
    String s = map.get(key);
    if (map.get(s) == null) {
        return s;
    }
    return s + "," + mapRecursion(map, s);
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean. You just have to be careful with endless recursion (e.g. if you have `{a=1, 1=a}`).

Comment: Yes this looks good but its looping only one level , I have map that contains multiple level of keys let me explain in better way.

Comment: Perfect! this worked with minor modifications. Thanks Ruslan!

Answer (score 1):

You can navigate the map recursively by starting at a key and returning the method call with its value.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RecurseMap {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a", "1");
        map.put("b", "2");
        map.put("c", "3");
        map.put("1", "4");
        map.put("4", "5");
        map.put("5", "a"); // Circular reference!

        navigate(map, "a");
    }

    public static <K, V> void navigate(Map<K, V> map, K key) {
        navigate(map, key, new TreeSet<K>());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <K, V> void navigate(Map<K, V> map, K key, Set<K> visited) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Current key: %s", key));
        if (!visited.contains(key) && map.containsKey(key)) {
            visited.add(key);
            navigate(map, (K) map.get(key), visited);
        }
    }
}
```

### Output

```
Current key: a
Current key: 1
Current key: 4
Current key: 5
Current key: a
```

Keep in mind, the method signature should be `<K, K>` or `<K>`, but I used `<K, V>` above to denote key, value relationship.

```
public static <K> void navigate(Map<K, K> map, K key) {
    navigate(map, key, new TreeSet<K>());
}

public static <K> void navigate(Map<K, K> map, K key, Set<K> visited) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Current key: %s", key));
    if (!visited.contains(key) && map.containsKey(key)) {
        visited.add(key);
        navigate(map, (K) map.get(key), visited);
    }
}
```

---

### Walking the map

**Update:** You can create a visitor class to evaluate the map key/value along the way.

```
import java.util.*;

public class RecurseMap {
    private static interface Visitor<K> {
        void visit(K key, K value, Map<K, K> map);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a", "1");
        map.put("b", "2");
        map.put("c", "3");
        map.put("1", "4");
        map.put("4", "5");
        map.put("5", "a"); // Circular reference!

        walkMap(map, "a", new Visitor<String>() {
            @Override
            public void visit(String key, String value, Map<String, String> mapRef) {
                System.out.println(String.format("Current key: %s", key));
            }
        });
    }

    public static <K> void walkMap(Map<K, K> map, K key, Visitor<K> visitor) {
        walkMap(map, key, visitor, new TreeSet<K>());
    }

    public static <K> void walkMap(Map<K, K> map, K key, Visitor<K> visitor, Set<K> visited) {
        if (!visited.contains(key) && map.containsKey(key)) {
            K value = map.get(key);
            visitor.visit(key, value, map);
            visited.add(key);
            walkMap(map, value, visitor, visited);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent `Java.lang.StackOverflowError`, if a loop occurs in the map, you may check if the value is already in, and give the continer (here a `Set`) to the method and not let the method create it itself

```
static Set<String> getValues(Map<String, String> map, String key, Set<String> res) {
    String val = map.get(key);
    if (val != null && !res.contains(val)) {
        res.add(val);
        res.addAll(getValues(map, val, res));
    }
    return res;
}

//Use as 
Set<String> res = getValues(map, "a", new HashSet<>());
System.out.println(res);
```